# Setting JButton size while using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, gridbaglayout

I have this simple JFrame and I want to know how can I set button's height to match exactly text field's height.
Why insets don't work on right side of the button? There is no padding between the button and the window border.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }

    public MyFrame() {
        super("My Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c;
        final Insets insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

        JLabel dbLocationLabel = new JLabel("Database file:");
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = insets;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        this.add(dbLocationLabel, c);

        JTextField dbLocationText = new JTextField();
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = insets;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 5;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 0.1;
        this.add(dbLocationText, c);

        JButton dbLocationButton = new JButton("...");
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = insets;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        this.add(dbLocationButton);

        this.setSize(500, 150);
        this.setLocation(300, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You should **always** have a main JPanel.  **Never** put components directly on the JFrame.  You will save yourself a lot of future grief.

2) You forgot the constraints on the JButton add.

3) I changed the fill on the JTextField to BOTH to make the JTextField higher.

Here's the changed code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }

    public MyFrame() {
        super("My Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c;
        final Insets insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        final Insets buttonInsets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 8);

        JLabel dbLocationLabel = new JLabel("Database file:");
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = insets;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        mainPanel.add(dbLocationLabel, c);

        JTextField dbLocationText = new JTextField();
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = insets;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 1;
//        c.gridwidth = 5;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 0.1;
        mainPanel.add(dbLocationText, c);

        JButton dbLocationButton = new JButton("...");
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = buttonInsets;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        mainPanel.add(dbLocationButton, c);

        this.add(mainPanel);
        this.setSize(500, 150);
        this.setLocation(300, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works nicely. The only thing is, I wanted to make buttun smaller, instead of a textField bigger. The reason is, I will have other txtfield in secon row which won't contain a button. So two textfields will have differend heights.

Comment: @John N.: Put a JButton in the second row and setVisible(false).  Honestly, most people don't care that buttons are bigger than text fields.

Answer (score 2):

**SSCCE:**

```
package stack;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SameHeight extends JFrame {

    JTextField jtf;
    JButton btn;

    public SameHeight(){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        jtf = new JTextField(30);
        btn = new JButton("Click Me");

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 7;
        gbc.gridheight = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        getContentPane().add(jtf,gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 8;
        getContentPane().add(btn,gbc);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SameHeight();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Explanation:**
Make sure that your `JTextField` and `JButton` have the same `gridheight`. Also, set the `fill` of `GridBagConstraints` to `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`. That way, your components will stretch to fit the width and the height.